# Using Json with Flickr to pull latest picture and the picture description

Tags: javascript, html, json, flickr

I've been using this script to get latest flickr image.

```
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
{
tags: "mount rainier",
tagmode: "any",
format: "json"
},
function(data) {
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
  $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
  if ( i == 3 ) return false;
});
});</script>
```

While it works perfect for displaying the latest image with a certain tag I have been trying to pull that latest pictures description as well and giving it a div id.

I've tried and failed. I was able to show a title.  Unfortunately the title was of the first Json result that is not an image.

Thanks